# ARKit – Cannot decode ARAnchor in MCSession

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, multipeer-connectivity, world-map

I'm testing out Apple's Multiuser AR demo app with ARKit 2.0 that was introduced in WWDC 2018: [Creating a multiuser AR experience](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/creating_a_multiuser_ar_experience).

The documentation says that after each device relocalizes to the same `World Map`, only the information needed to recreate each user action is shared among devices (e.g. if the user taps on the screen and a 3D object appears, only that new object's `ARAnchor` should be sent to other devices). For me, while it shows all the 3D characters that were placed by the sending device before it captured and sent a World Map, it doesn't show any objects that are added after the World Map has been sent. The error I'm getting says:

```
// can't decode data recieved from peer.
```

Has anyone had this issue and knows what it's about?

I haven't changed anything in the demo code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble but I kind of solved it in this way.

(1)first create a variable to check if the world map has send.

**var worldMapHasInited: Bool = false**

(2)Then in **func shareSession(_ button: UIButton)** add this line to the end below

*self.multipeerSession.sendToAllPeers(data)*

**self.worldMapHasInited = true**

(3)And finally in **func receivedData(_ data: Data, from peer: MCPeerID)**

**check if the world map has sent, if is sent, skip checking if the data contains   world map or not.**

```
    if !worldMapHasInited {
        if let worldMap = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: ARWorldMap.self, from: data)
        {
            //....
            // when received world map, set the receiver's 
            // worldMapHasInited to true  
            self.worldMapHasInited = true                                              
        }
    }
    else
        if let anchor = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: ARAnchor.self, from: data) {
            // ...
    }
```

**This will directly check if the data contains anchor or not.**

Answer (score 0):

In MultipeerConnectivity ARSession several peers share data among each other. But sent and received data must be, at first, archived and then unarchived using two instance methods of `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` classes:

```
func archive(worldMap: ARWorldMap) throws {

    let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: worldMap,
                                         requiringSecureCoding: true)

    try data.write(to: worldMapURL, options: [.atomic])
}
```

and:

```
func unarchive(worldMapData: Data) -> ARWorldMap? {

    guard let unarchievedData = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: ARWorldMap.self, 
                                                                           from: worldMapData)
    else { return nil }

    return unarchievedData
}
```

Hence, if you get the following message in Xcode Console:

```
"can't decode data received from peer"
```

it means the error occurred while transferring or unarchiving a ARWorldMap data.