# Deserializing ARWorldMap in Unity that was serialized with NSKeyedArchiver in native iOS

Tags: ios, swift, unity-game-engine, arkit

I have developed an iOS/ARKit app that functions as a content editor for my AR game. It has a fair amount of interface that I don't want to port over to Unity, but I want to be able to save my ARWorldMaps from the iOS editor app and load them into my Unity AR game.

I'm using NSKeyedArchiver to serialize my ARWorldMap like this:

```swift
func serializeMap(_ worldMap: ARWorldMap) -> Data {
    return try! NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: worldMap, requiringSecureCoding: true)
}
```

Any ideas how I could use those bytes returned from `serializeMap` to load the map in Unity using `ARWorldMap.TryDeserialize`?

Comment: Are the two types compatible and interoperable? If so, you should be able to save the archive to disk and then lid it from unity.

Comment: @ezpz, read my answer – https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52075159/arkit-cannot-decode-aranchor-in-mcsession/62596832#62596832

Answer (score 1):

It should look rather like

```
func deserializeMap(_ data: Data) -> ARWorldMap? {
    return try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: ARWorldMap.self, from: data)
}
```